Private endpoints for Azure Key vaults
Created Private end points for azure key vaults. Firewalls and virtual networks as Disable public access:

and private endpoints have been created:

I'm trying to access from my API getting Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link error.
Expecting key vault Access through private end points.

If you follow the link below :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview
Private endpoints enable connectivity between the same:

Virtual network
Regionally peered virtual networks
Globally peered virtual networks

So Virtual network to be enabled.
KeyVault and API App need to be on the same Virtual network or their Virtual networks needs to be peered.
